# iframe content height null in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i'm using jQuery to change the size of an iframe dinamically based on it's content so it doesn't display scrollbars. The script is pretty simple and it's working fine in IE9 but nothing happens in chrome, i added a small "alert" only for debbuging and i found out the the var "cont_height" is not defined in chrome.

All the files are in my computer, including the pages loaded in the iframe so there should be no cross domain issues.

The debugging tools in chrome give me this error: "Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match".

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#mainframe').load(function () {
                    var cont_height = $(this).contents().height();
                    alert(cont_height);
                    $(this).height(cont_height);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I tried with "$(window).load" instead of document ready but i don't think it's a timing issue, i'm not being able to access the data due to permissions or something. I'll really appreciate any hint you can give me. The solution con be in javascript also.

Comment: Chrome has issues with you running the files directly, without a webserver. It doesn't like that the domain is `null` (because there is no domain).

Comment: I see, can i set a phony domain or something then?, couse i will be evaluated using local files.

Comment: what @FritsvanCampen is saying is that if you're browsing your html with (`file:///C/myFile.html`) over the file system, it has a null origin and that causes the problem.  You can run these on a local web server and that'll sort it out (`http://localhost/myFile.html`).  If you want an easy web server to use and don't have IIS, Apache or something else running, you could install python and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the path that your html files are in from the command line on your machine.  Its a really light weight local web server.

Comment: I see, i'll check out the python webserver, seems like the lightweight choice i'm looking for. Still i have a question pending; this is for a college proyect and i'm still not sure how the professor will test the pages, most likely he will just run index straight from the computer. So, is there any way, my framed page can send a message to my main page saying "Hey, this is my body height"?, that would really cover all my bases. Thanks for your time and dedication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way I've found to resize the iframe based on it's content.

```
<script>
    function resizeMe(id) {

        var theFrame = document.getElementById(id);




        var theBody = (theFrame.contentWindow.document.body || theFrame.contentDocument.body)
        var newHeight = Math.max(theBody.scrollHeight, theBody.offsetHeight, theBody.clientHeight);

        theFrame.height = (newHeight + "px");

    }
</script>


<iframe id="helloworld" ... onload="resizeMe('helloworld')"></iframe>
```

You can have the iframe document call the parent document with parent.resizeMe('helloworld').

```
<body onload="parent.resizeMe('helloworld')">
...
</body>
```

or since you have jquery...

```
<body>
    ...
    ...
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            parent.resizeMe('helloworld');
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: It's a great and safe way to adjust the height and i appreciate it, but the proble is that it doesn't let me access the contentWindow or contentDocument of the iframe. Maybe there is a way that the iframe can send my main page it's own body height?

Comment: Is the iframe going to the same domain as your parent window? Or does it get it's content from another domain?

Comment: The iframe content is gonna be mine, in the same folder the main page is. I need the message comunication couse the page is gonna be tested locally, offline on a computer.

Comment: I believe chrome won't allow communication between an iframe and parent unless you are hitting an actual domain name(www.somedomain.com). If you are hitting localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000 it will not work because of security issues. So if I understand you correctly, this sounds like the issue. You might be able to add an entry to your hosts file for this. add: 127.0.0.1 localwebsite.com.

Comment: @teewuane, I am getting the `contentWindow ` as null.
I have to update the `iframe` `height` onResize.

Comment: @KuldeepBhimte Are you developing on your localhost or 127.0.0.1? If so, see my comment that is two comments up. Let me know!

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your support.

Comment: @teewuane I have some other issue with the iframe . I have posted it on the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54784044/anchor-tags-href-isnt-working-when-iframe-is-opened-in-a-react-dialog-model.